# How to import @material/theme and @material/textfield style to create own theme package

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, material-design

I'm trying to create a custom `@material/theme` package containing custom colors and only components used(`@material/textfield/mdc-text-field` in this example), following [this documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/theme/)

### @mycorp/scss

**variables.scss**

```
$primary-color: #ff742a;
$secondary-color: #ffd42a;
$text-color: #383838;
$background-color: #F6F6F6;
```

**material.scss**

```
@import './variables.scss';

// Update Theme
@use "@material/theme" with (
  $primary: $primary-color,
  $secondary: $secondary-color,
  $background: $background-color,
);

// Import only Text Field
@use '@material/textfield/mdc-text-field';
```

**index.scss**

```
@import './variables.scss';
@import './material.scss';
```

### Project

I'm using React and Webkit + Babel to run the project, and I installed `@rmwc/textfield` to generate the HTML.

I import my style on my `app.scss` by importing the index of the package:

`@import "@mycorps/scss/src/index.scss";`

I know that everything else is working fine (variables, ..) but **No Style for Material Design**.

### Another try

I Also tried to replace `@use` by `@import` in order to "write" the text-field theme (i guess ?) but I got the error when I try to build it:

```
ERROR in ./src/style/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./src/style/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "@include mixins": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".core-styles;"
        on line 30 of ../../../dev/mycorps/packages/mycorps-scss/node_modules/@material/textfield/mdc-text-field.scss
        [...]
>> @include mixins.core-styles;

   ---------^

 @ ./src/style/app.scss 2:26-201
 @ ./src/index.js
```

Same result when I tried both solutions without results:

- https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/351#issuecomment-298796798
- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804#issuecomment-586095020

Answer (score 1):

**Update !! This answer is NOT working when installed as usual.. ONLY when 
 used with `npm link`.**

Okay.. I figure it out after multiple try.

I have to have both `node-sass` and `sass` and also add `implementation: require('sass'),` into `webpack.config.js`:

```js
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
            }
          },
          { loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                // mdc-web doesn't use sass-loader's normal syntax for imports
                // across modules, so we add all module directories containing
                // mdc-web components to the Sass include path
                // https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/351
                includePaths: glob.sync(
                  path.join(__dirname, '**/node_modules/@material')
                ).map((dir) => path.dirname(dir)),
              },
              implementation: require('sass'),
              webpackImporter: false,
            }
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

I Also update the `material.scss` file :

```
@use '../variables.scss';

// Update Theme
@use "@material/theme" with (
  $primary: $primary-color,
  $secondary: $secondary-color,
  $background: $background-color,
);

// Import only Text Field
@import '@material/textfield/mdc-text-field';
```